# What is the largest file size of a single file my app can save?

Tags: iphone, filesize

I'm writing an iPhone app that needs to download files that are sometimes over 4 GB, and save them for file share in iTunes. Of course, I'm warning the user if insufficient space is available.

But is this actually possible on an iPhone? Does the file system support such huge files?

Secondly, will such an app be approved by Apple?

Comment: -1 for above comment ,, however don't have rep to do so

Comment: Hmmm, as large as the device gets I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely uses [Apples HFS Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) file system so max file size would be 8 EB (8 billion GB)

No idea about approval